# Is the following definition of integrals correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, definition

I'd imagine the idea of integrals summing up infinite slices would be formalized something like this:

$$\int_{k = 0}^x f \left( k \right) = \lim_{\omega \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^\omega f \left( {k x \over \omega} \right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You need to look up standard definitions in textbook. And note that definition of an integral is rather complicated to come just by intuition.

Answer (score -1):

No it not correct way to write an integration as this infinite sum rather you can write it like this

```
∫ˣf(k)dk = lim ω---->∞ (1/ω) Σ(k=0,xω)f(k)
```

I don't know how to type equations, sorry for that.

EDIT:
$$\int_0^x f(k)dk=\lim_{\omega\to\infty}\frac{1}{\omega}\sum_{k=0}^{x\omega}f(k)$$

Comment: This is worse than the OP's attempt.